# How can i get the text of a paragraph and then turn it into an integer in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple paragraph as:
`<p id="amt1">0</p>`
and have a button called to add to the amount as:
`<button id="addbtn1">+</button>`
I want it such that when i press the button the text in the paragraph is updated to 1 and after pressing it again is updated to two

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Please add some code snnipet first.

Comment: You should probably start with defining an `onClick` event handler.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please go through the help, tour and faq sections to learn what and how to ask. As it is, your question is considered "off topic" because "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html:

```
<p id="counter">0</p>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Javascript (remove comments for the code to work out of the fiddle):

```
//onload = function() {
  counter = document.getElementById('counter')
  add = document.getElementById('add')
  add.onclick = function() {
    counter.innerHTML = counter.innerHTML-0 +1
  }
//}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grabantot/o9v1cw7L/

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGxvZg

```
    $('#plus').click(function(){
       var x = Number($('#result').html());
      $('#result').html(x+1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var txtNode = document.querySelector('#number');
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
var count = 0;

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  txtNode.innerHTML = 'Number: ' + count++;
}, false);
```

Basically you create a button/input element for the button, and a p tag (or whatever element you want to hold the number) and save both elements into variables using querySelector (or any other getter).

Then what I did was initialized a counter variable.

Next, I added what's called an EventListener to the button element. These are used to perform events, so when you click, whatever function is passed will execute on click. Here I just set the p tag's innerHTML to the counter variable with the ++ operator after (means +1). And every time you click it adds 1 to the counter variable.

hope this helps.

here's a JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/puxefaxuki/edit?js,console,output